# Plotting outputs of model after each epoch of training Keras

Tags: python, keras

Using Keras and python :

```
model = Sequential()
...
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=1000, batch_size=512,validation_split=0.2)
```

Is there a way to get the outputs of the model for each epoch to plot them against train_y and maybe some more data to visualize how the model is doing while the model is being trained?

Comment: You can write your own [lambda callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/)

Comment: Try use TensorBoard https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard

Comment: @DimaFirst i didnt see that TensorBoard can show you the predictions the model has done through the training compared with the real y values, is it possible to see that in tensorboard?

Comment: @OfekRon, I think that lambda callback is better solution. Sorry, I inattentively read your question.